# MySQL replication error from 5.5 -> 5.6

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

i was now searching the whole web but can't find any solution for my problem.
I have an MySql Server, this is my Master and installed Version is 5.5.

My Slave has Version 5.6.

Show Slave Status on the Slave says that everything works well but i got some errors in the logs and no data will be replicated from master to slave.

```
 [Warning] Neither --relay-log nor --relay-log-index were used; so replication may break when this MySQL server acts as a slave and has his hostname changed!! Please use '--relay-log=***-relay-bin' to avoid this problem.
2017-01-20T12:00:22.986564Z 1 [Warning] Storing MySQL user name or password information in the master info repository is not secure and is therefore not recommended. Please consider using the USER and PASSWORD connection options for START SLAVE; see the 'START SLAVE Syntax' in the MySQL Manual for more information.
2017-01-20T12:00:22.987160Z 2 [Warning] Slave SQL for channel '': If a crash happens this configuration does not guarantee that the relay log info will be consistent, Error_code: 0
2017-01-20T12:00:22.987225Z 2 [Note] Slave SQL thread for channel '' initialized, starting replication in log 'mysql-bin.000003' at position 545, relay log './***-relay-bin.000002' position: 518
2017-01-20T12:00:22.988602Z 1 [Note] Slave I/O thread for channel '': connected to master '***@***:3306',replication started in log 'mysql-bin.000003' at position 545
2017-01-20T12:00:22.989390Z 1 [Warning] Slave I/O for channel '': Notifying master by SET @master_binlog_checksum= @@global.binlog_checksum failed with error: Unknown system variable 'binlog_checksum', Error_code: 1193
2017-01-20T12:00:22.989702Z 1 [Warning] Slave I/O for channel '': Unknown system variable 'SERVER_UUID' on master. A probable cause is that the variable is not supported on the master (version: 5.5.53-0ubuntu0.14.04.1-log), even though it is on the slave (version: 5.7.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1-log), Error_code: 1193
2017-01-20T12:00:22.992998Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2017-01-20T12:00:22.993366Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
2017-01-20T12:00:22.993386Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-01-20T12:00:23.047145Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
2017-01-20T12:00:23.047412Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
```

here is my slave status

```
mysql> show slave status \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: ***
                  Master_User: ***
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 545
               Relay_Log_File: ****-relay-bin.000004
                Relay_Log_Pos: 296
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000003
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 545
              Relay_Log_Space: 503
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 3
                  Master_UUID:
             Master_Info_File: /var/lib/mysql/master.info
                    SQL_Delay: 0
          SQL_Remaining_Delay: NULL
      Slave_SQL_Running_State: Slave has read all relay log; waiting for more updates
           Master_Retry_Count: 86400
                  Master_Bind:
      Last_IO_Error_Timestamp:
     Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp:
               Master_SSL_Crl:
           Master_SSL_Crlpath:
           Retrieved_Gtid_Set:
            Executed_Gtid_Set:
                Auto_Position: 0
         Replicate_Rewrite_DB:
                 Channel_Name:
           Master_TLS_Version:
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

This status looks fine but when i add some data to the master nothing happend to the slave.
I read a lot and the devs from mysql says that an replication from 5.5 to 5.6 is possible... So what did i do wrong ....

i think it is a problem wit  @master_binlog_checksum... but how can i handle this?

i also deactivated the check

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%check%';
+---------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name             | Value |
+---------------------------+-------+
| binlog_checksum           | NONE  |
| check_proxy_users         | OFF   |
| foreign_key_checks        | ON    |
| innodb_checksum_algorithm | crc32 |
| innodb_checksums          | ON    |
| innodb_file_format_check  | ON    |
| innodb_log_checksums      | ON    |
| master_verify_checksum    | OFF   |
| slave_checkpoint_group    | 512   |
| slave_checkpoint_period   | 300   |
| slave_sql_verify_checksum | ON    |
| unique_checks             | ON    |
+---------------------------+-------+
12 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Master_Host: *** are you hiding this information or it is really like this? What if you do something to the slave (i know it sounds strange), but it just replicates to the master? ;-)

Comment: Hi,

yes i really hiding some inforamtion. 
No i think it isn't possible that i replicate to the master.

Answer (score 2):

Your output indicated you have 5.7.17 as the slave version (not 5.6 as you indicated). You can't replicate more than one major version difference as the slave make assumptions that the master knows about (e.g.  system variable `binlog_checksum`).

Might be time to update your master version.